# Spanish special characters printed as garbage

Tags: linux, java, slackware

I am using slackware, and trying to print Spanish characters.

When I use

```
echo *special characters*
```

they display perfectly, but when I write a java program that accepts command line arguments, and simply prints it to console, and I feed it Spanish alphabets, it outputs junk characters.

I searched, and came across some solutions. I went into lang.sh, and added

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Now everytime I run the same  aforementioned program, it still prints garbage, different garbage, but garbage nonetheless. Although it does confirm that it is reading from lang.sh by printing

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

everytime I run the program.

If I check the default charset, it is also utf-8. If I run the same program on windows, with default charset as utf-8, it runs perfectly.

Help?

Comment: Is your console locale set to utf-8? I have `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` here. By default Slackware does *not* configure the console as utf-8.

Comment: In other systems I had the problem with UTF-8. For me it was enough to use ISO-8859-1 encoding. From the Java side, we set the reporting to UTF-8 in the maven <properties> section: `<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>`